# Pulvo / Pulvoro / Pudro. Kio estas la diferenco? What is the difference?

Tags: translation

Kio estas la diferencon inter Pulvo, Pulvoro, kaj Pudro? Ĉu ekzistas diferencon?

Laŭ Glosbe [Pulvo](https://www.glosbe.com/eo/en/pulvo) ŝajnas esti "gunpowder" kaj [Pudro](https://www.glosbe.com/eo/en/pudro) ŝajnas esti por la vizaĝo. In tiu okazo, kio signifas la vorto 'Pulvoro'? Ĉu ĝi nur estas ĝenerala vorto por "powder"?

---

What is the difference between Pulvo, Pulvoro kaj Pudro? Is there a difference?

According to Glosbe Pulvo appears to be "gunpowder and Pudro appears to be for the face. In that case, what does the word 'Pulvoro' mean? Is it just a general word for powder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pulvoro*](http://vortaro.net/#pulvoro) -> any powder

[pulvo*](http://vortaro.net/#pulvo) -> gunpowder

[pudro*](http://vortaro.net/#pudro) -> face powder

Those are just basic translations. The links will take you to the dictionary, where you will find more information.

There is another related root, [polv*](http://vortaro.net/#polvo) you might also want to look at.

Comment: Mi pensis do. Ĉu vizaĝpudro/vizaĝpulvo & pafilpulvo/pafilpudro estas akceptebla uzi? I thought so. Are vizaĝpudro/vizaĝpulvo & pafilpulvo/pafilpudro acceptable to use?

Comment: Vizaĝpudro / pafilpulvo are ok (the other two combinations are weird). For the first one, ŝmink/o(Z) is a pretty common alternative.

Comment: _Vizaĝpulvo_ would mean  _gunpowder for the face_. _Pafilpudro_  = _cosmetic powder for guns_.

Comment: If I ever write a book, I'm going to call it "vizaĝpulvo" as a joke. I don't know of any other language  where such silly words are possible even if they make no sense.